# I don't know what this sort of jQuery AJAX data : () would be interpreted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, opencart

I'm neither a newbie nor a professional in jQuery.

I'm editing a jQuery code related to opencard checkout section. In this section there is Javascript file responsible to send data to the server.

I have encountered an AJAX request whose data is wrapped like this:

```
url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method/validate', 
type: 'post',
data: $('#payment-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-method input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-method textarea'),
dataType: 'json',
```

And I don't know how it is interpreted, I mean I don't know why it is like this? It sure has a reason.

Previously I had seen people write there data : section of their ajax script like this:

```
data : key : value,
```

But here it is set inside of a `$(..)` without using `val()` or `html()` to get the value or without setting keys, can anyone please explain me the stuff in `data : $(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give a selector without value to the jQuery, it would figure out the value itself.

Using this, you have a more procedural and a less hard-coded approach.

jQuery eventually turns the selector into an appropriate key=value pair, where key is the name

of the element and the value is the value of the element.

Opencart makes use of this feature, too. As you have tagged your question also with Opencart.